# Examples of algebraic stacks without coarse moduli space?

Tags: stacks

Keel-Mori's theorem says an algebraic stack with a finite diagonal over a scheme S has a coarse moduli space. What is an example of an algebraic stack without coarse moduli space?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[A^1/G<sub>m</sub>] is one example. You can check that any G<sub>m</sub> invariant map from A^1 to a scheme is constant. Thus the map from [A^1/G<sub>m</sub>]  to the point is universal for maps to schemes, but is not a bijection on geometric points (since [A^1/G<sub>m</sub>] has two geometric points).

Check out Jarod Alper's [thesis](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.2242v3) to learn more.

Comment: This is super! I love it. 

Comment: @unknown (google): No.  